# "Files" can't be resized

Tags: nautilus

I am not able to change the size of my nautilus window. It is now small.[image]

What should I do to restore it to normal size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click in the window to make it active, then hold `ALT` and hit `space` - a small menu will appear at the top left corner of the window. You will see:

```
Minimize
Maximize / Unmaximize
Move 
Resize
Always on top
Close
```

"Unmaximize" is present if you have the window "maximized". 
"Move" makes the arrow keys usable for moving the window (press ESC to exit this mode), same for "Resize".

Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you're done with your adjustments.

Answer (score 7):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> and Middle Click and drag to change its size.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: note that your pointer should be at the edge of the window, i.e. it doesn't work in the middle of the window

Comment: Yes, and if it is close to one corner etc, that is what it drags from.

Comment: and they say the linux on the desktop will be usable any day now.  The mere existence of this question suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Gary haha, I know what you mean. The newest version of Ubuntu is a little easier, it’s got much larger window borders. I should probably update this answer in fact!

Comment: your answer is still quite valid for ubuntu 16.04 though

Comment: @Gary Yes, I'll add an 18.04 section when I get back from holiday and can install it!